# Intersecting regions of two files and printing combined result

Tags: python

I have two big files. I want to find common names in column 1 and column 2 of file1 and file2, respectively. The script below does it. Problem: I want to print also corresponding data from file1 in output, but it does not work. How to fix it?
file1.txt

```
GRMZM5G888627_P01   GO:0003674  molecular_function
GRMZM5G888620_P01   GO:0008150  biological_process
GRMZM5G888625_P03   GO:0008152  metabolic process
```

file2.txt

```
contig1 GRMZM5G888627_P01
contig2 AT2G41790.1
contig3 GRMZM5G888625_P03
```

Desired output,

```
contig1 GRMZM5G888627_P01  GO:0003674   molecular_function
contig3 GRMZM5G888625_P03  GO:0008152   metabolic process
```

Script,

```
f1=open('file1.txt','r')
f2=open('file2.txt','r')
output = open('result.txt','w')

dictA= dict() 
for line1 in f1:
   listA = line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
   dictA[listA[0]] = listA

for line1 in f2:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    query=new_list[0]
    subject=new_list[1]
    new_list.append(query)
    new_list.append(subject)
    if subject in dictA:
       output.writelines(query+'\t'+subject+'\t'+str(listA[1])+str(listA[2])+'\n')
output.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the

```
for line1 in f2:
```

listA isn't going to be mapped to the associated f2 line.  You stored them in dictA.

Once you test if the subject is in dictA, you need to retrieve the proper listA

```
for line1 in f2:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    query=new_list[0]
    subject=new_list[1]
    new_list.append(query)
    new_list.append(subject)
    if subject in dictA:
        listA = dictA[subject]
        output.writelines(query+'\t'+subject+'\t'+str(listA[1])+str(listA[2])+'\n')
output.close()
```

I don't understand why you are appending to `new_list` in here:

```
    query=new_list[0]
    subject=new_list[1]
    new_list.append(query)
    new_list.append(subject)
```

When processing the first line, you read in:

```
contig1 GRMZM5G888627_P01
```

Into `new_list`, giving you essentially:

```
new_list == ['contig1', 'GRMZM5G888627_P01']
```

Then you set `query` and `subject` to the two items in the list.  Then append them back onto it, giving you:

```
new_list == ['contig1', 'GRMZM5G888627_P01', 'contig1', 'GRMZM5G888627_P01']
```

Which you never use.  You should be able to just have:

```
for line1 in f2:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    subject=new_list[1]
    if subject in dictA:
        listA = dictA[subject]
        output.writelines(new_list[0] + '\t' + subject + '\t' + str(listA[1]) + str(listA[2]) + '\n')
output.close()
```

Also you are only writing 1 line, so `output.write` is fine.  And string addition is usually bad, so replaced by format.  Your `listA` stored strings, so I eliminated the `str()` call.

```
for line1 in f2:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    subject=new_list[1]
    if subject in dictA:
        listA = dictA[subject]
        output.write("{}\t{}\t{}{}\n".format(new_list[0], subject, listA[1], listA[2])
output.close()
```

Comment: Exactly, it wasn't associated. I see the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 ins = open('file1.txt', "r" )
    values=''
    dict={}
    for line in ins:
        arrayline=line.split()

        dict[arrayline[0]]='\t'.join(arrayline)


    file2=open('file2.txt', "r" )
    output = open('result.txt','w')
    for line in file2:
        array2=line.split()
        try:
            v=dict[array2[1]]
            output.write('\n'+array2[0]+'\t'+v)


        except:
            pass


    output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

```
In [1]: list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

In [2]: list2=[1,2,3,10,11,12,13]

In [3]: list1=set(list1)

In [4]: list1.intersection(list2)
Out[4]: {1, 2, 3}
```